# Google Maps Api V3: Overlay ImageMap with loading indicators

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, overlay, activity-indicator

I have an ImageMap overlay like the following:

```
var options = {
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return myUrl+"?x=" + coord.x + "&y=" + coord.y + "&z=" + zoom;
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true
};

var overlay = new google.maps.ImageMapType(options);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, overlay);
```

Because the images can take a while to load, i want to show load indicators for the map (those common animated gifs for AJAX calls). I am not sure if the usability would be better if there is only one indicator for the whole map, or one indicator for each overlay tile. So, solutions and thoughts for both are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS to hide the div that holds your map.  Use `addEventListenerOnce()` on your map to listen for the `idle` event or perhaps the `bounds_changed` event.  (You may need to experiment to see which event gives you the better result.)    When the event fires, make the div that holds your map visible.

There are at least two reasonable ways to show the progress indicator while waiting for the event to fire.  You can have it in a separate div that (in addition to revealing the map div) you hide when the event fires.  Or you can wrap the map div inside another div and set the background image for that div to be your animated progress indicator image.

In the end, your code might resemble this block I had to write not too long ago:

```
document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.visibility = "hidden";
var mapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
                getTileUrl: function(coord,zoom) {
                    return 'img/tiles/'+zoom+'/'+coord.x+'/'+coord.y+'.png';
                }
            });
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, mapType);
google.maps.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() { document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.visibility = "visible";});
```

Comment: Thanks, the listener with idle seems to be a good possibility. But i don't want to hide the map because everytime i move the map it should remain visible and just a load indicator should be added, maybe with another overlaying div on the map canvas.

Comment: You can choose to only hide the map on initial load.  Of course, then you don't get the progress indicator when the user pans or zooms.  Although the more I think about this, the more I wonder if the solution might not be to just find a way to reduce the load times for the tiles.  If you didn't create your tiles with MapTiler or gdal2tiles.py, you might want to look into that.  And it might be worth running your tiles through pngcrush and pngnq.  I assume you're not generating tiles on the fly. If so, then that might be the real problem, unless you have gargantuan computing power.